# Bias adjustments in Box-cox back transformation

Tags: python, scipy

I learned that the scipy.special.inv_boxcox() function compute the inverse of the [Box-Cox transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtSom.jpg). 
The bias problem will make the result (actually median) smaller than the mean. 
Is there a function that can adjust the bias and return the mean value?

Comment: Can you provide a link to a clear explanation of "the bias problem"?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser The "Forecasting: Principles and Practice" introduces the bias problem in the last part of chapter 3.2 "Transformations and adjustments". Here is the link: [link](https://otexts.com/fpp2/transformations.html)